# Including Jquery mobile locally in android app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Jquery mobile styles are not rendering in android App when storing the jquery mobile css and js file locally in assets folder of android project. But the same is working by including the jquery mobile files from CDN. Help me

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SAMPLE</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/TamkeenJQ.js"></script>
   -->

  </head>
  <body>
   <div data-role="page" id="page1"> 
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
     Header
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    content
    <button onclick="changePageFn()">Change Page</button>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
     Footer
    </div>
   </div> 

   <div data-role="page" id="page2"> 
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
     Header
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    content
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
     Footer
    </div>
   </div>

  </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First add the jquery css files.
2. Then add the jquery 1.9.1 js file.
3. then add the jquery mobile 1.3.2 js file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks some issue in your implementation.

If you have included the correct path of your js and css files related to jquery mobile.

**Solution:** Reverify the path of js and css files.

Comment: I have pasted jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css in css folder inside the www folder in assets folder. My html files is inside www folder of assets. I have included the script and css as follow <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>

Answer (score 0):

Use the following order in the head tag

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquerymobile-1.3.2.min.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquerymobile-1.3.2min.js"></script>
```